# parameter passing to partition is not working in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to pass partition value as parameter.

```
SET runmdt = date_sub(current_date,5);
```

The below query is working fine.

```
SELECT
cal_id,caller_name,location
from
amobe_tbl a
WHERE a.create_dt IN
(select DISTINCT create_dt from mt_call 
WHERE create_dt between date_sub(current_date,20) and current_date)
and a.create_dt=${hiveconf:runmdt};
```

When insert into partition table it's not working.

```
SET runmdt = date_sub(current_date,5);
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE amobe_tbl PARTITION (create_dt=${hiveconf:runmdt})
SELECT
cal_id,caller_name,location
from
amobe_tbl a
WHERE a.create_dt IN
(select DISTINCT create_dt from mt_call 
WHERE create_dt between date_sub(current_date,20) and current_date)
and a.create_dt=${hiveconf:runmdt};
```

FAILED: ParseException line 1:92 cannot recognize input near 'date_sub' '(' 'current_date' in constant 
create_dt is date data type.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got your answer but in any case the WHERE clause makes no sense (`WHERE a.create_dt IN (...) and a.create_dt=${hiveconf:runmdt}`)

Answer (score 1):

#### 1

Hive variables are nothing but a text replacement mechanism.
The replacement is done before parsing and execution.

```
hive> set hivevar:v1=se;
hive> set hivevar:v2=l;
hive> set hivevar:v3=ec;
hive> set hivevar:v4=t 1+;
hive> set hivevar:v5=2;
hive> ${hivevar:v1}${hivevar:v2}${hivevar:v3}${hivevar:v4}${hivevar:v5};
OK
3
```

#### 2

Use dynamic partitions

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

SET runmdt = date_sub(current_date,5);
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE amobe_tbl PARTITION (create_dt)
SELECT
cal_id,caller_name,location,${hiveconf:runmdt}
from
amobe_tbl a
WHERE a.create_dt IN
(select DISTINCT create_dt from mt_call 
WHERE create_dt between date_sub(current_date,20) and current_date)
and a.create_dt=${hiveconf:runmdt};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help